# how to make a function in android studio to take a string barcode and return the price and name of products?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

the QR is already made and i can take the number of the barcode but I have a problem with the function that asks the real-time database to give me back the price and the name of the product.

Comment: We are going to need the code that is responsible for the database pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already implemented a function?

In your case, I'd use something like this:

```
public Item getItemByBarcode(final String barcode) {
Item item = null;

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").orderByChild("barcode").equalTo(barcode)
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
                            item = task.getResult.getValue().toObject(Item.class);
                            return item;
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Is there another solution without using a Firebase .. I think there is nothing is working with me

Comment: your question was related to Firebase in general which is why I posted this solution. In my personal opinion, Firebase is the easiest realtime database solution to use as its pretty popular, efficient and tons of documentation out there. What is the issue that you are having?

Comment: can I contact you at any social media APP ??

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
String barcodeResult = ""
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/path/to/data").orderByChild("qrContent").equalTo(barcode).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
          Log.e("TAG", task.getException().toString());
        } else {
          Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
          item = task.getResult.getValue().toObject(Item.class);
          return item;
        }
    }
});
```

Just make sure you replace the reference path and field name in the query.